# Laravel package config does not merge

Tags: php, laravel, service-provider

I am developing several packages and would like to have a single config file for all of them if they are to be published.

Inside my service provider I did this:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__ . '/config/custom.php' => config_path('custom.php'),
    ]);
}

public function register()
{
    $this->mergeConfigFrom(
        __DIR__ . '/config/custom.php', 'custom'
    );
}
```

Config:

```
return [
    'containers' => [
        ...
    ]
];
```

And surely enough, if I publish it, it creates the file with values inside. But if a file already exists, having different keys:

```
return [
    'xxxyyy' => [
        ...
    ],
];
```

publishing doesn't do anything. I would expect it to look like:

```
return [
    'xxxyyy' => [
        ...
    ],

    'containers' => [
        ...
    ]
];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the same name of the config file existed, the `publish` command doesn't do anything. And it's also doesn't merge the config file, and only override the config file with option `--force`

Comment: If it doesn't do that, what is the point of whole `mergeConfigFrom` method? What does it "merge"?

Comment: It allows user can override (merge config values from 2 files) some default config values from your package without touch the package source code. Example in file config of package set ['foo' => 'bar'], and if user want to change `['foo' => 'foobar']`, they should publish your configuration file in the laravel app to do that.

Comment: `vendor:publish --force` would do what you're describing without using `mergeConfigFrom`

Comment: I mean that's function it merge config values from 2 files into 1 then load into app when bootstrapping, it doesn't merge the file content literal. And you do nothing wrong

Comment: Yes, and if `custom.php` already exists, it should merge published `custom.php` with one I am giving it inside of my package. Merging 2 files into 1. My files are not getting merged.

Comment: I already said that in the first comment, that isn't how the publish command works. If you want to merge literally, you may write your own publish command.

Comment: Then again, I don't understand what's the purpose of `mergeConfigFrom`? Documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/packages#configuration states that I can merge my config with published copy.

Comment: They use `array_merge()` config values, not the file content. If you want know how it merge, you should read `mergeConfigFrom` function source code to see how it work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else is baffled by this, I have tested several cases and here is my explanation ([official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/packages#configuration)).

`$this->publishes` part enables the package config to be published by `vendor:publish` command. Nothing to explain here.

`$this->mergeConfigFrom` part enables the package config to be merged with currently published copy. Merge in this case means merged from Laravel `config()` scope.

This means that going to `artisan tinker` and running `config('key')` (where key is name of your config file) will return nothing if there is no published file and you don't have `mergeConfigFrom`. If a file is published and has other key value pairs which are not present in your package config and you have `mergeConfigFrom` present, `config('key')` will return merged array of values from a published file together with values from your config.

If a file with a same config name exists in your root config folder, and your package internally uses the same config name but you don't have `mergeConfigFrom`, `config('key')` will return only contents of a file inside root config folder, and will ignore everything from your package as you didn't provide a way for Laravel to see this as a "global" configuration. Your package will keep internally using the package config, but from app scope you will not be able to fetch it.